# How do I use the selection_single method from the Vega Altair library to change the size of a selected image?

Tags: image, altair, vega

I'm using Vega Altair to generate an interactive chart and I would like for the user to be able to select an image in the chart, which is then enlarged and not see through. Below you can find the intended code. However this yields an error stating:

"altair.utils.schemapi.SchemaValidationError: '{'condition': {'param': 'param_1', 'value': 100}, 'value': 50}' is an invalid value for `width`. Valid values are of type 'number'.  Additional properties are not allowed ('condition', 'value' were unexpected)'expr' is a required property 'band' is a required property"

```
single = alt.selection_single()
    altair_chart = alt.Chart(source
        ).mark_image(
            width= alt.condition(single, alt.value(100), alt.value(50))
        ).encode(
            x='id',
            y='id',
            url='img_path', 
            tooltip=['id', 'created', 'img_path','gpt_prompt']
        ).properties(
            width='container',
            height=400
        ).configure_mark(
            opacity= alt.condition(single, alt.value(0.7), alt.value(0.4))
        ).add_selection(single
        ).interactive()
```

I've tried to look for solutions, but none of the provided fixes seem to work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

I've looked at the example code from altair, but was unable to replicate it for the image size and opacity. Furthermore I checked several stack overflow threads most notable those listed below, but also here I wasn't able to replicate the results.

1. [Combine hover and click selections in Altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66108224/combine-hover-and-click-selections-in-altair)
2. [Python: Altair Condition Color Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381202/python-altair-condition-color-opacity)

Comment: I think `width` currently only accepts numbers and not conditions https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html. Generally, some params express expressions https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#expressions instead of conditions, but it doesn't look like this is the case for `width` either (although you could try just in case the docs are wrong there)